# What is the process of changing my distributer license?

Tags: ios, licensing

A company just gave me their Enterprise edition log-in so that I can distribute my app to their employees only. I've only ever distributed from my personal license.

How do I change the licensing and company identifier in xcode so that I will be able to distribute the app to their employees? is there a simple tutorial out there?

This is probably a silly question, but google wasn't turning anything up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want to change the account in Xcode ? Menu Xcode / Preferences / Accounts

Here you can add / delete accounts (Apple ID)

I thinks Xcode will import automatically the certificats linked to the new account into your keychain. Just use it to sign the App.